# Why does $\operatorname{Ad}_h((S\otimes 1)(Q))=\epsilon(h)(S\otimes 1)(Q)$ in a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

I'm reading a proof that in a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra $H$, $(S\otimes 1)Q$ is $\operatorname{Ad}$-invariant. Here $Q=\tau(R)R$, where $R$ is the invertible element in $H\otimes H$ satisfying all the quasi-triangular properties.

It goes, if $R=R'^1\otimes R'^2$ is the second copy of $R$ being transposed in the definition of $Q$, 
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ad}_h(S\otimes 1)(Q)) &= h_1(SQ^1)Sh_2\otimes h_3Q^2Sh_4\\
&= h_1(SR^1)(SR'^2)Sh_2\otimes h_3R'^1R^2Sh_4\\
&= h_1(SR^1)Sh_3(SR'^2)\otimes R'^1h_2R^2Sh_4\\
&= h_1Sh_2(SR^1)(SR'^2)\otimes R'^1R^2h_3Sh_4\\
&= \epsilon(h)(S\otimes 1)(Q)
\end{align*}
$$

For the last equality, shouldn't $h_1Sh_2=\epsilon(a)$ and $h_3Sh_4=\epsilon(b)$, where $\Delta h=a\otimes b$, which would give a coefficient of $\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)=\epsilon(ab)$ in front? Not $\epsilon(h)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right, but $\varepsilon(ab)=\varepsilon(h)$ -  so the proof you quoted is also right. For: 
$$\varepsilon(ab)=\varepsilon(a)\varepsilon(b)=\varepsilon(\varepsilon(a)b)=\varepsilon(h).$$
The 2nd equality used that $\varepsilon$ is $k$-linear.